# Updating packages in MikTeX

Tags: pdftex, miktex, installing, miktex-update

When I run the `MikTeX's Update wizard` on my `Windows 10 machine` it shows a list of several packages with all being check marked (selected) as shown in a snapshot below. Does that mean the older version of all these packages are already installed on my system and need to be updated or does that mean that the wizard is showing the list of MiKTeX packages available online that were recently updated and that they are not necessarily on my system?

**Note**: I've a basic installation of MiKTeX on my machine. I don't know most of which of these packaes I need. I'm assuming the list shown in the wizard is of the packages that were installed by default during basic installation of MiKTeX. But want to make sure during upgrade wizard launch I don't endup installing packages I don't really need.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All but one of the packages listed in your screenshot are 'core' components of a LaTeX set up; whilst you might not use every single one, sufficient people do that they are part of the 'basic' MiKTeX install. (The one oddity is `genealogy`, but that might be one you've installed either by design or accident yourself.) The update wizard only updates *installed* packages: you will not be adding anything to your system using it.

You can always check what is installed using the MiKTeX Package Manager (available on the Start menu).